# How can you install Jenkins on linux mint or ubuntu using oracle jdk instead of openjdk?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, java, apt

I already have Oracle JDK/JRE installed on my computer but when I try to download and install Jenkins 2.35 using "sudo apt-get install jenkins" the openjdk dependency also gets fetched. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What version of Java do you have installed? Where/how was it installed? You can always remove it after; AFAIK the apt-get will look for a Java and if it's not found, it'll snag the OpenJDK version.

Comment: I have Oracle jdk 8 installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this link : 
https://serverfault.com/questions/250224/how-do-i-get-apt-get-to-ignore-some-dependencies

You can try the --nodeps flag with apt-get.
Or download the package and install it using dpkg with the option --ignore-depends.

Comment: Thank you. I did manage to install it finally but I had to reinstall jdk 8 via apt.

Answer (score 1):

I finally did manage to install Jenkins. I had to install Oracle jdk 8 via apt.

```
  sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I added this step as per the Java 8 installer comments:

```
  sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Then I added JAVA_HOME into /etc/environment to match the jvm path.

I was then able to install jenkins via apt:

```
  sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

I followed the steps given here with some additional steps added in:

[How to install Oracle JDK on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)